# The name for a flowery expression - not a cliché

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases, word-usage

My English teacher years ago referred to the name for a flowery expression designed to make the speaker or writer sound more educated than they actually are. I am confident it wasn't a cliché because there is no metaphorical element, nor are they idioms. 
Some examples would be:

- In the fullness of time
- Be that as it may
- Time and time again
- Clouding my judgment
- The end justifies the means
- More often than not
- Casting aspersions
- Against my better judgement
- An educated guess
- The less said the better
- In the interests of time
- All manner of means

You often hear defendants or near-illiterate people suddenly use one of these expressions mid-sentence.

What is the word for them?

Comment: A lot of these are quotations. For example "fullness of time" comes from the King James Bible (Galatians 4:4). I would say that they are idioms but there may be a specific term for a quotation that has become a widely-used idiomatic phrase.

Comment: Purple prose? Not that I'm ever guilty of that, don't ya know.

Comment: Have you looked for synonyms at [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cliche), [PowerThesaurus.org](https://www.powerthesaurus.org/cliche) and/or [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cliche)? Or searched for ['high-flown'](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=high-flown) here?// I'd be happy with some of your examples. Though there's certainly a time and place for everything.

Comment: Some of them are most ***definitely*** idioms. I object to the statement: 
"You often hear defendants or near illiterate people suddenly use one of these mid-sentence." Believe me, as a "highly educated" native speaker of English, I can assure you, OP, that is simply not true. And finally, not all clichés are metaphors. Whatever gives you that mistaken idea? These phrases actually mark a speaker as "educated" and "The ends justifies the means" is actually an aphorism. "All manner of means", that's a new one on me.

Comment: I agree with Edwin Ashworth. See this as well:http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/avoiding-cliches/

Comment: Some of these "high-flown" expressions may be part of  a "pompous" speech.

Comment: I might say, *grandiloquent* fits your description, but I wouldn't call any of your examples grandiloquent and I wouldn't say the user of any of those would necessarily sound and more educated than they actually were.

Comment: Most of these aren't ‘flowery’ at all, they're just perfectly common, idiomatic collocations.

Comment: Also, these _are_ clichés, the definitive character being they are used so often that they've lost most meaning.

Comment: The first poster might be looking for the word, bombastic, but his examples aren't bad enough.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have no idea why people are calling these ornate and flowery. They are the very opposite of that: overwrought expressions so  hackneyed that not even the glue factory will take them. *Vide infra*. :)

Comment: Since two months have now passed with no edits to clarify what exactly is meant by the asker stating that cliches and idioms are not what they are looking for and then immediately following that with a list of cliched idioms, I have now voted to close the question as unclear.

Answer (score 5):

## The year 19 ʙᴄ’s twin gifts *urbi et orbi*

[image: Large thumbnail from https://nature.desktopnexus.com/wallpaper/746676, fair use]

<sub><sub>“Purple Dreams” wallpaper from [nature.desktopnexus.com](https://nature.desktopnexus.com/wallpaper/746676/)</sub></sub>

It was during the eighth year of the reign of Caesar Augustus, that selfsame year in which Agrippa completed his great Aqua Virgo, when Horace sent as an epistle to the consul Piso the poem we have come to call the [*Ars Poetica*, whose lines 14–21](http://nodictionaries.com/horace/ars-poetica/1-23) contain history’s first mention of ***purple prose***. There Horace writes that

> *Important incipits
>
>   full of profound professions
>
>   see often the **purple patch**
>
>   or two, broadly resplendent,*

applied to them.

As Agrippa’s aqueduct would prove a font rich enough to sustain the Eternal City in all the ages since, so too would the ageless wisdom of Horace’s poem come to inspire writers of the world even unto our own day.  If only they had read more closely! :)

---

## Hackneyed phrases and tired refrains

[image: A hackney coach, 1482, from *London in the Nineteenth Century*, by Walter Beasant]

<sub><sub>A hackney coach from 1842's *London in the Nineteenth Century* by Walter Beasant</sub></sub>

Unlike what several other posters seem to feel, I hold that the various expressions you mention are ***not*** the flowery language of purple prose.  They are not unrelated, fanciful language used to beautify simple passages to make these more attractive to bored readers, yet which nonetheless serve mostly to distract with their long-winded discursions into matters unrelated to the one at hand.

On the other hand, the opening section of this post which you have just done me the honor of reading might be said to be an example of “purple prose”, but I do not believe that this is the sort of thing that you are referring to  at all.

Rather, yours are overwrought expressions repeated so often that our ears tire of hearing them.  They are like the repeated refrain of an old familiar tune which the entire room sings along to in mindless unison, words that everyone knows and has heard so often before than no thought need be paid to their automatic repetitions.

For this reason, I believe that ***hackneyed*** is the best word to describe the sort of annoyingly repetitious phrases you have listed. The website World Wide Words discusses the origin of this word and its evolution into extended uses in [an article](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-hac1.htm) that includes the following text, with bold emphasis mine:

> Horses of the *hackney* type were often worked heavily, in the nature of things that were hired out to all and sundry. So the word evolved in parallel with the previous sense to refer figuratively to something that was **overused to the point of drudgery.** By the middle of the sixteenth century, *hackney* was being applied to people in just this sense, and was abbreviated about the start of the eighteenth century to *hack*, as in *hack work*; it was applied in particular to literary drudges who dashed off poor-quality writing to order — hence its modern pejorative application to journalists.
>
> Hackney horses were also widely available and commonly seen, to the extent that they became commonplace and unremarkable. So yet another sense evolved — for **something used so frequently and indiscriminately as to have lost its freshness and interest, hence something stale, unoriginal or trite.** The adjective *hackneyed* communicated this idea from about the middle of the eighteenth century on.

The annoying and pretentious business jargon that [Forbes rants against](http://www.forbes.com/sites/groupthink/2012/01/26/the-most-annoying-pretentious-and-useless-business-jargon) is the same sort of thing: overused clichés (a *cliché* need involve no metaphor) that people keep mindlessly repeating:

> The next time you feel the need to *reach out, touch base, shift a paradigm, leverage a best practice*, or *join a tiger team*, by all means do it. Just don't say you're doing it.

Hackneyed refrains like those in your list or the ones in Forbes’ drive the people who notice them stark-raving crazy while adding nothing to the writing. Good writers avoid them like the plague.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it *flowery prose.* There is not a strict definition of what is it, but everyone can recognize it. In my opinion, it consists of using too many fanciful descriptions and clichés, but also difficult expressions to explain simple subjects or  even melodramatic exaggerations.

It is too easy to fill your prose with adjectives, adverbs and purple flowers. I'm already feeling guilty for the way I wrote this answer. It isn't too ornate, right? :)

Comment: The examples given in the question are not flowery at all. They are not fancy and ornate embellishments, just overworked old phrases.

Comment: @tchrist You're right, they're not fancy. On the other hand, If one uses too many clichés and overworked old phrases, the text ends up full of words and expressions that say nothing, becoming "flowery" in a sense. I believe that some use them to beautify their prose, not realizing that they sound pretentious. So, I agree with you that the examples are not strictly flowery prose, but I also think that there is people who use some of them as decorative details.

Answer (score 0):

#### Purple Prose

> A generally pejorative term for writing or speech characterised by ornate, flowery, or hyperbolic language.

([Grammar.about.com](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/purpleproseterm.htm))

Comment: Could whoever down-voted explain why?

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but please see my own answer for why I do not believe these to be examples of purple prose.

Answer (score -1):

I would say these examples are not necessarily used to sound 'more educated' or 'pretentious' but just to articulate your speech. These can be termed 'long-winded;verbose idioms' which indeed are circumlocutory rather than laconic. It's just figure of speech, though.
I hope using these words doesn't make me 'wordy' or 'prolix', which is something that can be used to describe such people (pejoratively).